# EntryNodes and ExitNodes

Tags: configuration

Sono un nuovo utilizzatore di TOR.

Lo uso per vedere la TV Svizzera dall'Italia.

Per farlo nel file torrc-defaults ho inserito: EntryNodes {CH} e ExitNodes {CH}.

Tutto funziona perfettamente.

Io ho trovato online questa feature in modo del tutto casuale
.
Perché questa feature di cambiare la nazione con EntryNodes e ExitNodes non è
possibile farla direttamente dall'interno del sw?

Io ho trovato online questa feature in modo del tutto casuale.

Inoltre perché  non è possibile avviare due istanze di TOR contemporaneamente?

Infatti mi servivano per avere contemporaneamente la visione della TV Svizzera e di quella Italiana.

Pensate sia possibile attivare queste due funzionalità all'OTTIMO TOR?

---

I'm a new user of TOR.

I use it to watch TV Switzerland from the Italian.

To do so in the torrc-defaults file I entered: EntryNodes {CH} and ExitNodes {CH}.

Everything works perfectly.

I've found this feature online casually.

Because this feature of changing the country with EntryNodes and ExitNodes is not
Can you do it directly from within the sw?

I've found this feature online casually.

Also why can not I start two instances of TOR at the same time?

In fact, I needed to have both the Swiss and Italian TV views at the same time,

Think you can enable these two features at the TOP TOR?

Answer (score 0):

I comandi inseriti in testa al mio file torrc-defaults sono:

EntryNodes {CH}
ExitNodes {CH}

Su alcuni siti/forum ho visto anche il comando: StrictNodes 1 messo dopo EntryNodes.

Devo metterlo anche io?

C'è qualche comando da mettere dopo ExitNodesz?

Grazie

The commands inserted in the top of my torrc-defaults file are:

EntryNodes {CH}
ExitNodes {CH}

On some sites / forums I also saw the command: StrictNodes 1 put after EntryNodes.

Do I have to put it myself too?

Is there any command to put on after ExitNodesz?

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't use this for both Entry and Exit nodes. If you wish to only exit from a specific country (geoip isnt accurate anyway) then *only* set ExitNodes.

Comment: StrictNodes 1 lo devo mettere? o no?                                                         StrictNodes 1 do I have to put it? or not?

Comment: StrictNodes means that if it can't build the requested circuit it will fail, and won't build any circuit, rather than deciding to use a different relay.